# Class member function get won't return a value

Tags: c++

My problem is that my GetTitle() function does not return a value.

The code for my class Book is finished and I am still in the middle of finishing my main() code for a project and was testing a specific part. I was testing my functions with user input to see if they worked how they should.

The functions I am testing is SetTitle() and GetTitle(). I receive no error when I run my code but my GetTitle() function does not return a value. I have googled and looked up other stack over-flow questions similar and just cannot see why this is happening.

An example when I run the code and input the string "Test":

```
 Enter the book title:
 Test
    If this is after the book title the test worked
```

What is supposed to be outputted is:

```
Enter the book title: 
Test
Test   If this is after the book title the test worked
```

My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class Book {
public:
    void SetTitle(string title_input);
    string GetTitle();
    void SetAuthor(string& author_input);
    string GetAuthor();
    void SetCopyRightYear(int copyright_year_input);
    int GetCopyRightYear();
    void PrintBook();

private:
    string title;
    string author;
    int copyright_year;
};

 void Book::SetTitle(string title_input) {
      string title = title_input;
   }
     string Book::GetTitle() {
         return title;
     }
     void Book::SetAuthor(string& author_input) {
         string author = author_input;
     }
     string Book::GetAuthor() {
         return author;
     }
     void Book::SetCopyRightYear(int copyright_year_input) {
         int copyright_year = copyright_year_input;
     }
     int Book::GetCopyRightYear() {
         return copyright_year;
     }
     void Book::PrintBook() {
         cout << "Title of Book: " << GetTitle() << endl;
         cout << "Author of Book: " << GetAuthor() << endl;
         cout << "Copyright Year: " << GetCopyRightYear() << endl;
     }


int main ()
{
    string title_input = "";
    string author_input = "";
    int copyright_year_input = 0;


    Book book1;
    Book book2;
    Book book3;
    Book book4;

    cout << "Enter the book title: " << endl;
    cin >> title_input;
    book1.SetTitle(title_input);
    cout << book1.GetTitle() << "   If this is after the book title the test worked!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are creating a local variable in the setter and setting the value of it. It has no relation with your object

```
string title = title_input;
```

It is not setting the value of the attribute of the method. Change it to

```
title = title_input;
```

Comment: /home/ubuntu/workspace/lab25/lab25.cpp:52:13: error: ‘title_input’ was not declared in this scop This is my error when I do this.

Comment: @testtest can you confirm the error is in the setter line or any other line?

Answer (score 2):

In function setTitle you are creating a local variable title which hides the actual title varibale so don't use `string` before it. And this way change every setter function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class Book {
public:
    void SetTitle(string title_input);
    string GetTitle();
    void SetAuthor(string& author_input);
    string GetAuthor();
    void SetCopyRightYear(int copyright_year_input);
    int GetCopyRightYear();
    void PrintBook();

private:
    string title;
    string author;
    int copyright_year;
};

void Book::SetTitle(string title_input) {
      title = title_input;
}
 string Book::GetTitle() {
     return title;
 }
 void Book::SetAuthor(string& author_input) {
      author = author_input;
 }
 string Book::GetAuthor() {
     return author;
 }
 void Book::SetCopyRightYear(int copyright_year_input) {
      copyright_year = copyright_year_input;
 }
 int Book::GetCopyRightYear() {
     return copyright_year;
 }
 void Book::PrintBook() {
     cout << "Title of Book: " << GetTitle() << endl;
     cout << "Author of Book: " << GetAuthor() << endl;
     cout << "Copyright Year: " << GetCopyRightYear() << endl;
 }


int main ()
{
    string title_input = "";
    string author_input = "";
    int copyright_year_input = 0;


    Book book1;
    Book book2;
    Book book3;
    Book book4;

    cout << "Enter the book title: " << endl;
    cin >> title_input;
    book1.SetTitle(title_input);

    cout << book1.GetTitle() << "   If this is after the book title the test worked!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at your `SetTitle()` function. You are declaring a local string variable with exactly the same name as your member string variable. When the function is called you are setting the local variable only, not the member variable.

Comment: Okay. I believe I understand what you are saying. How would I fix this problem? I believe I would have to use pass by reference but tried earlier would only get errors.